# Can comparison between curves be achieved statistically to group into similar and different sets?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, equivalence, curves

I have a set of aggregate grade data and want to know if it is possible to determine if there are groups of samples of similar grade fraction using R studio.

Some of the data:

[image: excel data]

Column A contains sample labels (A1 contains 'Sample' as a title)
Row 1 B1 to K1 contain sieve sizes in micrometers corresponding to sieve sizes 32mm to 75um
B2 to K34 contain percentage of sample passing each sieve size for each of the samples.

1. Is it actually possible to see if the the samples fall into similar groups using statistical methods.
2. Assuming 'YES' has anyone ever actually achieved this in R studio {or do I need to head back over to Stack Overflow and ask the lovely people on there for more help?

Edit: A taster of what the data looks like plotted on grade curve.. To my eye it looks like A and B could be similar, G appears to be different to all, the rest seem to be similar to each other... OR is it just pattern matching when there is no numerical substance!
[image: example grading curve plotted in excel. X axis is log sieve size]

Comment: Welcome to CV. The geological literature has a great deal to say.  That would be a [good place to begin](https://www.google.com/search?q=grain+size+distribution+plot).  Usually one plots the passing fraction against the log of the sieve size: this represents the *empirical distribution function.*  There are a *huge* number of statistical ways to compare distribution functions, depending on what characteristic(s) of the distribution are important to you.

Comment: thanks so much for the comment - I've only previously used visual comparisons - for example demonstrating conformity with grading envelopes - and log of size is used (and can soon be calculated if useful in any part of the analysis!) :)    I have about 30 curves and some 'look' different - but I have no idea on how to 'prove' difference or similarity.  [I'll put a graph up of the data I have so far in the question - that might help?]